# How to stop the form from submitting

Tags: forms, input, submit

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

it is for captcha

```js
function drawcap() 
 {

 var captcha=Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000000);
      document.getElementById("txtdraw").value=captcha;  
        }
```

for submitting the form

```js
        function validate()
        {
            var str1=document.getElementById('txtdraw');
            var str2=document.getElementById('txtinput');
            if(str1==str2){    
            return true;}
            else{
            alert("fill correct captcha"); 
            return false;
        }}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: aliceblue">
```

form for submitting and validating it

```html
        <form action="home.jsp" method="get" name="login" onsubmit="return validate();">
            <fieldset style="align-self: center; height: 250px;">
                <center><legend>login</legend></center>
                <center><table style=" background-color: seashell; border:black; border-style: double; ">
                    <tr><td><label>Username</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" required/></td>
                    <tr><td><label>Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password"  required/></td></tr>
```

captcha code in this

```html
                    <tr><td>Captcha</td><td><input type="text" readonly id="txtdraw"></td>
```

input by the user

```html
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtinput" required=""/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" value="refresh" onclick="drawcap();" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="login"/></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/><td></tr><br>
                    <tr><td><a href="#">New Here</a></td><td><a href="#">Forget Password</a></td></tr>
                </table></center>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need to do this.

in ***java scripting*** you need to write **.value** to get a *VALUE* of input the field.

```js
function validate()
{
  var str1  = document.getElementById('txtdraw').value;
  var str2  = document.getElementById('txtinput').value;
  if(str1!=str2){    
    console.log("fill correct captcha"); 
    return false;
  }else{
    console.log('Correct')
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="home.jsp" method="get" name="login" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" id="txtdraw">
    <input type="text" id="txtinput">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry.. not understood

Comment: @ruchikajain Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form return false>
   <div> <input type="text">
   </div>
</form>
```